# Angular upgrade from version 14 to version 15

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am trying to update the Angular version from 14.2.11 to 15.x.x. But, while running the update command (ng update @angular/core@15 @angular/cli@15) I am getting the below error:

```
gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version was set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - looking for Visual Studio version 2022
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS running in VS Command Prompt, installation path is:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Users\my_name\AppData\Local\Microsoft"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - will only use this version
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2022 (17.6.33815.320) found at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - missing any VC++ toolset
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2022 (17.6.33815.320) found at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found VC++ toolset: v143
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found Windows SDK: 10.0.20348.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - does not match this Visual Studio Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - could not find MSBuild in registry for this version
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version does not match this VS Command Prompt or the
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS installation cannot be used.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail
```

Version details:

```
Node : 18.12.1
TypeScript: 4.8.2
node-gyp: 8.4.1
node-sass: 8.0.0
npm: 8.19.2
```

Running npm config list gives me the below output:

```
; "builtin" config from C:\Users\my_name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\npmrc

prefix = "C:\\Users\\my_name\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"

; "global" config from C:\Users\my_name\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc

; msbuild_path = "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\Msbuild\\Current\\Bin\\MSBuild.exe" ; overridden by user
python = "C:\\Users\\my_name\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39"

; "user" config from C:\Users\my_name\.npmrc

Files\Microsoft = "Visual"
msbuild_path = "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\Msbuild\\Current\\Bin\\MSBuild.exe"

; node bin location = C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
; node version = v18.12.1
; npm local prefix = C:\Users\my_name
; npm version = 8.19.2
; cwd = C:\Users\my_name
; HOME = C:\Users\my_name
; Run `npm config ls -l` to show all defaults.
```

Comment: The earlist version of Angular that NodeJs 18 supports is 15. But based on the error you have not started building your Angular project. How is this error being triggered? Are you trying `npm run build` from the CLI, or did you trigger a build from VS Studio?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue, by simply uninstalling the node-sass package and installed sass only. Looks like node-sass is deprecated in the newer angular versions.